# Install Mysql 5.7 on High Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, mysql-5.7

I want to install mysql 5.7 on my Mac OS 10.13.5. However, brew install mysql installs version 8.0 which is not suited for my project. Forgive me if this question was asked before but I could not find a solution.

Comment: Did you try this? https://gist.github.com/benlinton/d24471729ed6c2ace731

Answer (score 4):

Now it's bit differently

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ brew install mysql55
```

This installs a specific version 5.5 which exists along with 8.0
Also mysql entry should be added to .bash_profile to make sure it load and then server start should be done.

```
$ brew services start mysql@5.5
```

Below command gives the sequence of how the files are loaded in sequence.

```
 $ mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf
     order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

While installing first mysql server instance works perfectly, installing a different version of mysql instance should be configured properly and the paths of installation, log files and other components have different path.

Installation paths be found here, for eg.

```
mysql -> ../Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysql
```